# How exactly can cong be well-typed?

Tags: agda

I was looking at the definition of `cong`:

```
cong : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} (f : A → B) {x y} → x ≡ y → f x ≡ f y
cong f refl = refl
```

And I couldn't understand why it is well-typed. In particular, it seems like the implicit argument of `refl` must be both `f x` and `f y`. To make things more clear, I wrote a non-implicit version of equality, and attempted to replicate the proof:

```
data Eq : (A : Set) -> A -> A -> Set where
  refl : (A : Set) -> (x : A) -> Eq A x x

cong : (A : Set) -> (B : Set) -> (f : A -> B) -> 
       (x : A) -> (y : A) -> (e : Eq A x y) -> Eq B (f x) (f y)
cong A B f x y e = refl B (f x)
```

This results in a type error:

```
x != y of type A when checking that the expression refl B (f x) has type Eq B (f x) (f y)
```

As one would expect. What could I possibly have instead of `(f x)`? Am I missing something?

Comment: `refl` is `f x` and `f y` since a pattern match on `x \equiv y` was performed, for agda they are the same. Your proof doesn't work because you haven't pattern matched on `e`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependent pattern matching at your service.

If we make a hole in your `cong`

```
cong : (A : Set) -> (B : Set) -> (f : A -> B) ->
       (x : A) -> (y : A) -> (e : Eq A x y) -> Eq B (f x) (f y)
cong A B f x y e = {!refl B (f x)!}
```

and look into it, we'll see

```
Goal: Eq B (f x) (f y)
Have: Eq B (f x) (f x)
```

so the values are indeed different. But once you pattern match on `e`:

```
cong : (A : Set) -> (B : Set) -> (f : A -> B) ->
       (x : A) -> (y : A) -> (e : Eq A x y) -> Eq B (f x) (f y)
cong A B f x y (refl .A .x) = {!refl B (f x)!}
```

the fact that `x` is the same thing as `y` is revealed and the context is silently rewritten: each occurrence of `y` is replaced by `x`, so looking into the hole we now see

```
Goal: Eq B (f x) (f x)
Have: Eq B (f x) (f x)
```

Note that we can write

```
cong A B f x .x (refl .A .x) = refl B (f x)
```

i.e. do not bind `y` at all and just say that it's the same as `x` via a dot-pattern. We gained this information by pattern matching on `e : Eq A x y`, because once the match is performed we know that it's `e : Eq A x x` actually, because that's what the type signature of `refl` says. Unification of `Eq A x y` and `Eq A x x` results in a trivial conclusion: `y` equals `x` and the whole context is adjusted accordingly.

That's the same logic as with Haskell GADTs:

```
data Value a where
  ValueInt  :: Int  -> Value Int
  ValueBool :: Bool -> Value Bool

eval :: Value a -> a
eval (ValueInt  i) = i
eval (ValueBool b) = b
```

when you match on `ValueInt` and get `i` of type `Int`, you also reveal that `a` equals `Int` and add this knowledge to the context (via an equality constraint) which makes `a` and `Int` unifiable later. That is how we're able to return `i` as a result: because `a` from the type signature and `Int` unify perfectly as we know **from the context**.

Comment: hey, thank you. Do you happen to have any resource on dependent pattern-matching (i.e., how to implement it)?

Comment: @MaiaVictor, I think the pioneer here was Conor McBride ([thesis](http://strictlypositive.org/thesis.pdf)). Ulf Norell described how he did this in Agda ([thesis](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/thesis.pdf)). The modern way to do dependent pattern matching is described by Jesper Cockx ([thesis](https://jesper.sikanda.be/files/thesis-final-digital.pdf)).